# Cyclic Behavior of Iterated Simple Rational Functions

Tags: number-theory, analysis

I noticed that for the (real) function 
$f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$, $f(f(f(x)=f^3(x)=x$ for all real $x$.

This surprised me, and I was naturally curious about rational functions that elicit the identity after 4 or 5 or, in general, $n$ iterations.

I looked at rational functions of the form $f(x)=\frac{1}{z-x}$ for $z\in\mathbb{R}$ and wondered for which $z$ did $f^n(x):=f(f(...f(f(x))...))=x$.

After playing around for a bit on Wolfram and Desmos, I came up with the following conjecture: If $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $n\ge2$ and$f(x)=\frac{1}{2\cos(\frac{\pi}{n})-x}$, then $f^n(x)=x$.

Note that I do not claim that $f$ is the only rational function of the form $f(x)=\frac{1}{z-x}$ where $z\in\mathbb{R}$.

---

So I have a few questions:

1) Is this conjecture true?

2) How would someone go about proving it, if it is true?

3) Is this a well-known theorem or a somewhat-immediate corollary or special case of a well-known theorem? If so, what is that theorem?

4) How would I find all $z\in\mathbb{R}$ such that if $f(x)=\frac{1}{z-x}$, then $f^n(x)=x$? Is such a thing easy to do?

5) What field of math would ask questions like this?

Answer (score 1):

The conjecture seems to be true and  if it is, it could be proved by mathematical induction.I checked it for up to $n=4$ and it worked. There are other values for $z$ for example for $n=3$,  we also have $z=-1$ and for $n=4$ we have $z=\pm \sqrt 2$ and $z=0$

Note that with $f^3
=f$ we have also $f^5=f$ and $f^7=f$,....

You find these type of questions in discrete dynamical  systems.